# What should I do at, and what should I know about, bike shows?

Tags: shopping

The Toronto bike show is this weekend. I've never been to it, in previous years, or to any other. Apart from what my LBS told me briefly about the show last year, and the show's web site, I don't know what to expect.

I think the show is for consumers, LBSs, and manufacturers: I'm a consumer (I commute by bike).

[Click to visit the Spring Show page](http://www.bicycleshowtoronto.com/springshow.html)

Comment: You make it sound like you're getting married. "Never been married before, what do I do, what should I expect..." How about if you just go to the show and, if you like it, stay awhile, if you don't, leave. Pretty simple?

Comment: When I go to these, I usually wind up ogling bikes that I can't afford. A lot of times though, these shows will offer products for sale at a discount.

Comment: Doesn't the website pretty much explain it? Looks like fun to me! But then I'm a bike geek.

Comment: Be sure to leave checkbook, credit cards, and all but about $20 cash at home.

Comment: Bring your camera. Take pictures. Do a [blog](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com) post with lots of pictures.

Answer (score 8):

Ok. It's basically a trade show and exhibition. According to your link it appears to be typical of trade shows/exhibitions.

***1. What should I do?*** Walk around. Explore. Watch events. Shop for products of interest. Ogle bikes and collect brochures. And also, talk with manufacturers about things you find of interest.

***2. What should I know about?*** It's not a test, so you probably don't need to know anything in particular. You might "know" about products that you're considering, but other than that...

Otherwise, you'll get to see new bikes, new bicycling technologies, and new accessories. And, it appears that you'll get to watch some bmx and mtn bike events.

Last thing... Bring along a friend who is vacillating about taking up bicycling. There's nothing like pretty gizmos to get someone started. ;~) And things like this are usually way more fun when you have a friend along.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason people go to these bike shows is to look for bargains. If you intend to go, bring a list of bicycle stuff related items (tires, wheels, pedals, saddles, etc.) along with their going range of prices on the web and at bike stores. Compare the prices in the bike show to those in your list and if it looks like you found a bargain then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The Toronto Bike show is great, I have gone many times.  I actually will be there on Sunday as well.

Enjoy seeing the bikes, the BMX stunt shows, and all the groups showing their group ride routes.

But bring lots of cash.  Lots of deals for cash to be had.  Look at bike shops bargain bins for parts you might need cheap.

I usually go looking for close outs on clothing, since I have gotten amazing deals that way before.

Comment: My LBS (who may be biased) said that the best bargains are not at the show, but, rather, on clearance in the store before the show. A bigger range at the show, though, presumably.

Comment: @ChrisW Obviously this is 11 years too late: If Toronto isn't a stop on a trade show "circuit," then the _last day_ is a prime time to buy stuff that traveling vendors don't want to pack up and schlep back home. I don't know if there's a pattern for deals from local vendors, but it sounds like Geoff has experience with that.